# Why "do_package in both covered and notcovered."?

Tags: yocto

I am given a basic working yocto image from a manufacturer and would like to add sqlite to this image. In order to do so I looked through the open-source layers on openembedded and found [these recipes](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/45261/).

I proceeded to copy the recipe and inc file which can be found on the webpage above and added it to the manufacturer's yocto release inside my own separate layer. I had to update the syntax of the sqlite recipes, ie replace all of the ':' with a "_". Eg I changed:

```
PACKAGECONFIG:class-native ?= "fts4 fts5 rtree dyn_ext"
```

to:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_class-native ?= "fts4 fts5 rtree dyn_ext"
```

Apparently this is because syntax with a colon belong to a new Yocto syntax while underscores are an older syntax. The manufacturer's recipes never contain colons anywhere but underscores.

I then tried building the image and got loads of errors like these:

```
...
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/libxcb_1.14.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc_10.2.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/vim/vim_8.2.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/procps/procps_3.3.16.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/net-tools/net-tools_1.60-20181103.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/meta-alb/dynamic-layers/core/recipes-support/rng-tools/rng-tools_5.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/bash/bash_5.0.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/shadow/shadow-securetty_4.6.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-benchmark/stressapptest/stressapptest_1.0.9.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/opkg-utils/opkg-utils_0.4.3.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/autoconf/autoconf_2.69.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/base-passwd/base-passwd_3.5.29.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/icu/icu_67.1.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/parted/parted_3.3.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/rpcbind/rpcbind_1.2.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/fbset/fbset-modes.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/libmpc/libmpc_1.2.0.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4_1.4.18.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/libmnl/libmnl_1.0.4.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
ERROR: Setscene task /home/user/Desktop/john/work/foo/yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-buildessential.bb:do_package in both covered and notcovered.
...
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

I tried googling around to understand what this error means or what causes this error. No success so far.

Comment: I am also receiving a mass of such errors. Was the rerun a solution and got no serious impact?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes encounter also this error which came from (I use yocto dunfell so bitbake 1.46) [here](https://git.openembedded.org/bitbake/tree/lib/bb/runqueue.py?h=1.46#n2021)

The comment says it is a bug but I didn't find a clear way to reproduce it yet. Anyway, it doesn't seem to be so impacting, just rerun your task and it should be fine.

Comment: the rerun seems like is helping. could it be because of the circular dependency of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this "... in both covered and notcovered" in yocot bitbake file.
My solution is to change the number in opensource's patch filename.
The origin number in filename is repeated, such as 0001-xxxx, 0001-xxxx... Maybe do_package are both in these two patch. I change one to 0002-xxx and modify the bbappend to relocation the patch. The error is solved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34723404)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this occurs when i am building a yocto project and the process is interrupted by external or system freeze occurs.  I've not pinpointed the exact timing of the build execution and the crash, but have seen this happen multiple times during my year-long development on a Kirkstone/Mickledore yocto project.

To fix, i simply rerun the build process.

Note that typically I can interrupt (CTRL-C) the build process without running into the 'setscene task' issue.